# How to work with a dependency that is built on Spring boot into typical spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have built a jar say ABC around Activiti with spring boot dependencies and packed as a dependency. 
The dependencies that are added are as follows on the jar we built.

1. Spring-boot-starter-tomcat
2. Activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic
3. Activiti-spring-boot-starter-rest-api
4. Activiti-spring-boot-starter-actuator
5. In dependency management we added the artifact spring-boot-depenencies.

When I inject this jar ABC as a dependency in to a typical spring application I run into multiple issues. Is there a way that I can use this jar in typical spring application (with XML based configuration)?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more details? as in what issues you run into? What error are you getting? Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I am getting Lifecycle exception and concurrent exception while starting the Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You can inject Spring boot dependenc in two ways:

- By specifying it as a parent (explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven))
- By specifying it as another dependency using `<dependencyManagement>` tag (explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent))

Once done, you can use Spring boot's classed into your application.

> When I inject this dependency in to a typical spring application I run
>   into multiple issues

Are these issues `ClassNotFound` and `MethodNotFound` exceptions? If yes then you might have conflicts in different dependency versions.

Comment: My question now is, is it possible to add a spring boot dependency in a typical xml configuration based spring application that runs on an external tomcat.

Comment: Edited the question.